# How to distinguish web socket result of two subscribe channel?

Tags: c#, websocket

I m new to web socket but now too much clear about how it work. My problem is here right below: I want to distinguish the result of two events.

```
interface IWebSocketMethod
{
    void GetTicker();
    void GetOrderBook();
    void GetTrades();
}
abstract class WebSocket
{
    private WebSocket4Net.WebSocket Socket;
    public WebSocket(string webSocketUrl)
    {
        Socket = new WebSocket4Net.WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
        Socket.Opened += new EventHandler(OpenEventHandler);
        Socket.Error += new EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs>(ErrorEventHandler);
        Socket.Closed += new EventHandler(CloseEventHandler);
        Socket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(MessageReceivedEventHandler);
        Socket.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    public virtual void OpenEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Open");
    }
    public virtual void ErrorEventHandler(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
    }
    public virtual void CloseEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection close");
    }
    public virtual void MessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    public virtual void Request(string data)
    {
        Socket.Send(data);
    }

}
class BitFinexWebSocket : WebSocket, IWebSocketMethod
{
    public BitFinexWebSocket():base("wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws")
    {
        GetTicker();
        //GetOrderBook();
        GetTrades();
    }
    public void GetTicker()
    {
        var obj = new { @event = "subscribe", channel = "ticker", pair = "BTCUSD" };
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToLower();
        Request(body);
    }
    public void GetOrderBook()
    {
        var obj = new { @event = "subscribe", channel = "book", pair = "BTCUSD" };
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToLower();
        Request(body);
    }
    public void GetTrades()
    {
        var obj = new { @event = "subscribe", channel = "trades", pair = "BTCUSD" };
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).ToLower();
        Request(body);
    }
    public override void MessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

now in this code i m subscribing two event but in MessageReceivedEventHandler how i can distinguish the result. Or i have to create multiple web socket connection. Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I created a base class model with a channel property that I deserialized first to determine the channel.Then once identified which channel you can deserialize it again with the appropriate response model for that channel.

```
public enum Channel
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "ticker")]
    TICKER,
    [EnumMember(Value = "book")]
    BOOK,
    [EnumMember(Value = "trade")]
    TRADES
}


public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
}

public class TradeResponse : Response
{
    public string Symbol;
    public DateTime time;
    ...
}

public override void MessageReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Response res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(e.Message.ToString());

    switch (res.Channel)
    {
        case Channel.TRADES:
            TradeResponse trade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeResponse>(e.Message.ToString());
            // ...
            break;
        case Channel.BOOK:
            break;
        case Channel.TICKER:
            break;
        default:
            throw new System.Exception("Unsupported channel");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
}
```